# Streaming Webcam RTMP support

Tags: javascript, flash

Okay I'm using this code; and I'm curious to know why it isn't streaming to my RTMP server; I have tried connecting to my Red5 RTMP server through OBS which is a broadcasting program and it works fine but when using this script it doesn't broadcast the webcam I'm just wondering if I'm missing any variables which is preventing me from connecting to the rtmp server or something. Thank you for any help!

```
    <embed src="webcam.swf"
           flashvars="server=rtmp://ip/path/usertoken"
           bgcolor="#ffffff"
           width="800"
           height="900"
           quality="high"
           allowScriptAccess="always"
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
           pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

In the readme of the setup there are some variables which I didn't understand how to use so I'm going to paste them below:

```
### FlashVars

* server : rtmp server
* stream : rtmp stream to publish
* token  : (optional)
* camerawidth : default 640
* cameraheight : default 480
* camerafps : default 15
```

this is the main one that I didn't understand
    with `swfobject`:

```
    var flashvars = {server : "rtmp://localhost/live",
                     stream : "plop"};
    var params = {};
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("webcam.swf", "myId", "300", "120", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Comment: hey Lewis, what's `webcam.swf`is it a custom one? do you have source code for it?

Comment: @www.eugenehp.tk Hey thankyou for the reply; I don't have a source code for the .swf if you would like I can upload the .swf if that would be of use. I really appreciate the response.

Comment: hey Lewis, yeah, copy the link to the swf here, and let's see if I can help you with that.

Comment: Here you can find the whole directory. [link](https://github.com/AF83/webcam-streaming) Thankyou for thelp @www.eugenehp.tk