# How to send webcam video to rtmp

Tags: javascript, webrtc, webcam, rtmp, live-streaming

I am using https://demo.avideo.com/ for live streaming purpose.

I am trying to live stream my web cam
This site show option to live stream web cam but experimental.

When I see source code after I press web cam stream.

```
swfobject.embedSWF("<?php echo $global['webSiteRootURL']; ?>plugin/Live/view/webcam.swf", "webcam", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Similar to this [Streaming Webcam RTMP support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102035/streaming-webcam-rtmp-support)

Now I am trying to implement with

> getUserMedia

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (err0r) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
}
```

Web cam is asking for permission to access.

**But how to send the web cam video to rtmp server.
Is there any way? Or Are there any other option to implement this.**

Note: *I used https://obsproject.com/ for send to rtmp server It's working fine with web cams, screen sharing, videos and all*

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`WebCam -> RTMP` is not possible in the browser directly. You will need to send video to a backend, and then bridge to RTMP.

I shared an existing solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61008559/5472819